# R: Wrong transformation from SpatRast (terra) to stars object

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, r, terra, stars

When I transform my `SpatRast` object to a `stars` object, suddenly the the location of my origin changes. I need the location of the origin to be an exact point (376491.4,5875118.5, EPSG:25833), as I am using the raster for further analysis.

Here is the code:

```
library(terra)
x_diff <- 1573.114
studyarea_r <- rast(xmin = 364636.4, xmax = 387627.9,    
                    ymin = 5862203.7, ymax = 5889920.8,     
                    resolution = c(x_diff,x_diff), 
                    crs = "EPSG:25833")

values(studyarea_r) <- runif(ncell(studyarea_r))
origin(studyarea_r) <- c(376491.4,5875118.5)
```

This gives me the following raster

```
studyarea_r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 18, 15, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 1573.114, 1573.114  (x, y)
#extent      : 363906.5, 387503.2, 5862533, 5890849  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N (EPSG:25833) 
#source(s)   : memory
#name        :       lyr.1 
#min value   : 0.006194775 
#max value   : 0.994340585
```

Then I transfrom it

```
library(stars)
studyarea_stars_trial <- studyarea_r |>
  st_as_stars()
```

And I get following output

```
stars object with 2 dimensions and 1 attribute
attribute(s):
              Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean  3rd Qu.
lyr.1  0.006194775 0.2884413 0.4827618 0.5060741 0.764638
            Max.
lyr.1  0.9943406
dimension(s):
  from to  offset    delta                refsys x/y
x    1 15  363906  1573.11 ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N [x]
y    1 18 5890849 -1573.11 ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N [y]
```

However, when I plot the two,  there is a big difference (the point is the origin I defined earlier):

[[image: SpatRaster plot1]

[image: stars object plotted in mapview()]

What is the best workaround for this? I need the raster as a `stars` object for further analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coerced a SpatRaster to a stars object, and you believe that this changed the georeferencing of the data. I do not think that is the case. I think that what you see is distortion due to your approach to mapping, not a difference in the underlying data.

Your evidence is a map, but you do not show how you made it. From the looks of it, it appears that you used some browser-based mapping tool, perhaps with the mapview package?

These browser maps generally use the Mercator coordinate reference system (crs). But note that your raster data has another crs: UTM zone 33N. So I assume that your data was projected to Mercator to make the map. That requires estimating values for an entirely new raster. This can be done in different ways, but it looks like you (knowingly or not) used nearest-neighbor resampling. No matter how you do it, your raster will not, and cannot, be the same after projecting.

You can prove that nothing changed by coercing the stars object back to a SpatRaster with `x <- rast(studyarea_stars_trial)`. That returns an object that is identical to the original SpatRaster.